# Working out min/max from file input

Tags: java

Within my java program i require the highest and lowest values of 'answer' from the file input part and display them back to the console. I am aware of using the math.min/math.max commands but unable to see how to accommodate them into my code?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment {
private static Scanner input;
public static ArrayList<String> validList = new ArrayList<String>(); 


public static boolean isInt(String userinput) { 
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(userinput); // Try to parse. Makes sure    that the values entered are actual numbers
            return true; // Boolean value to show if the equation entered is valid or not
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
            System.out.println("Please enter a  valid expression!");
            return false; 
        }
    }
        public static boolean isValidLine(String line) {
            line = line.trim();
        if (line.length() <= 4) { // Trims the lines down to 4 and ensures there is no spaces being included
                return false; 
            } 
        else 
            {
            String[] calcarray = new String[3];
            calcarray = line.split(" ");
            String operators = new String("[+\\-\\*\\/]"); // Validator using regular expressions to check the operator used

        if (isInt(calcarray[0].toString()) && isInt(calcarray[1].toString()) && calcarray[2].matches(operators)) { // Checks that the operator in the string matches the ones in the regular expression 
            return true; 
    }
        else 
    {
            return false;
    }
    }
}

static void display(String msg)
        {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
static void processInput() throws IOException
{
String keyboardInput = new String();
Scanner kbScan = new Scanner(System.in);
int answer = 0;
while (true){
        display("Please enter an equation");
        keyboardInput = kbScan.nextLine(); 
if (isValidLine(keyboardInput)) {
    String[] equation = new String[3];  // We know that this is only going to contain 3 to be valid
    equation = keyboardInput.split(" "); // split this up, as it's stored with the spaces.
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(equation[0]); 
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(equation[1]);
switch(equation[2]) { // This case switch checks the third position of the string to decide which operator is being used. It then works out the answer and breaks to the next instruction

case("+"):
    answer = num1 + num2;
break;
case("-"):
    answer = num1 - num2; 
break; 
case("/"):
    answer = num1 / num2;
break;
case("*"):
    answer = num1 * num2;
break;
}
    display("Your post fix expression: " + equation[0] + " " + equation[1] + " " + equation[2]);
    display("Your calculation: " + equation[0] + " " + equation[2] + " " + equation[1] + " = " + answer);
}
else
{ 
    display("The equation you entered is invalid");
}
}
    }

static void fileInput() throws IOException
{
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try
    {
    String currentLine = new String();
    int answer = 0;
    //Open the file
    display("Enter File Name: "); 
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input.nextLine()); // make a input stream
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream)); // pass input stream to a buffered reader for manipulation
    String strLine; // create string vars
    //loop to read the file line by line
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   { // Whilst the buffered readers read line method is not null, read and validate it.
        currentLine = strLine; 
        if(strLine.trim().isEmpty())
        { 
            display("You have entered a blank line, the program will now exit");
            System.exit(0); 
            }
    if(isValidLine(currentLine)) 
    { 
        String[] filearray = new String[3];
        filearray = currentLine.split(" ");             
    int val1 = Integer.parseInt(filearray[0]);
    int val2 = Integer.parseInt(filearray[1]);
        display("Your expression is: " + filearray[0] + " " + filearray[1] + " " + filearray[2]);
    switch(filearray[2]) { 
    case("+"):
            answer = val1 + val2;
        break;
    case("-"):
            answer = val1 - val2; 
        break; 
    case("/"):
            answer = val1 / val2;
        break;
    case("*"):
            answer = val1 * val2;
        break;
        }
    display("Your calculation is " + filearray[0] + " " + filearray[2] + " " + filearray[1] + " = " + answer);
    }
    }
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    display("Please Enter a valid file name");
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
while(true)
{
    display("Enter F for file calculator or K for keyboard input");
Scanner optionScan = new Scanner (System.in);
String optionInput = optionScan.nextLine();
char letterInput = optionInput.charAt(0);

switch (Character.toUpperCase(letterInput))
{
case 'K':
    processInput();
    break;
case 'F':
    fileInput();
    break;
case 'Q':
    System.exit(0);
}
}

}   
}
```

Comment: At least fix your indentation.

Comment: Where's your main? Where should that min/max thing happen?

Comment: The main is at the bottom. When the fileInput method processes the text file entered and displays the answer to each sum within the file it needs to also say which is the highest and lowest answer out of all of the sums if that makes sense? Also it is for a reverse polish notation calculator if that helps

Comment: Perhaps you sample is a bit too long, it is always better to reduce the problem to its core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2 `private static` fields to keep track of your min and max answer. So first I would create 2 new fields with your other fields. I gave them the max integer and min integer value just so it is easy to do the comparison later.

```
private static Scanner input;
public static ArrayList<String> validList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private static int minAnswer = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private static int maxAnswer = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Then in your `fileInput` method, after you do the calculation, here is where you can utilize `Math.max` and `Math.min`. Something like this:

```
display("Your calculation is " + filearray[0] + " " + filearray[2] + " " + filearray[1] + " = " + answer);
minAnswer = Math.min(answer, minAnswer);
maxAnswer = Math.max(answer, maxAnswer);
```

After the user enters the blank line to excape, you will have the max and min answer in those fields. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** I created fields since I think you need access to the min/max values in your main method. If you only need access to these values in your `fileInput` method (print the values after doing all the calculations, then forget about them), then I would just create 2 `int` *local* variables instead in your `fileInput` method.